# cannot configure ProxyPass using VirtualHost on cpanel + apache

Tags: meteor, cpanel, whm

1. I can see website load successfully when I use `xyz.com:3000`. I have meteor website hosted on VPS.
2. Inside **cpanel**->**Apache Configuration**->**Post VirtualHost Include**->**2.4.27**, when I added below peice of config. I cannot see it run on *`xyz.com`* instead of *`xyz.com:3000`*

   ```
   Listen 80
   <VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80> 
   ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:3000/"
   ServerName xyz.com 
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, you would want to just run you Meteor app on port 80? You can do this by adding `--port 80` into `meteor` command

Comment: I have another website running on port 80. So i did this virtualhost configuration.

Comment: In that case, shouldn't your `<VirtualHost ...:80>` contain your `xyz.com` instead of IP?

Comment: Hi, did the problem solved? How to do it,  I have same problem

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439981/apache-forward-all-requests-for-a-specific-domain-to-an-express-server/73398435, also check https://ferpython.com/setup-fastapi-in-cpanel

Answer (score 0):

The way you do it means server wide. The apache include files edited through WHM -> Apache configuration apply server wide. In your case you need it for a specific vhost and not for all the vhosts on the server.

In order to create a custom template for an apache vhost on your cPanel/WHM you should follow the instruction from official cPanel documentation:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Custom+Templates