# Apache forward all requests for a specific domain to an express server

Tags: node.js, apache, express

I'll start by saying that I'm not an Apache expert nor an Apache beginner to that matter. I have an express server that listens on port 443. I host it on a VPS that's running Centos7 that hosts about 40 other websites, and as far as I know servers them using Apache (I didn't really configure it, I used cPanel and WHM).

Now, since I know that Apache is listening to port 443 in order to serve the websites, I wonder how I can combine Apache with my Express server (If there's a way at all).

I know I could just change the port of my express app, but then the port will show up on the address bar on my application and I don't want that.

I don't really know what to try since my knowledge in Apache is limited. I'll be happy to provide with more details should you'll need them.

Thanks alot!

EDIT:

I tried editing the default httpd.conf file under `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`.

This is what I did:

```
<VirtualHost MY-IP:443>
ServerName <mydomain.com>
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
 ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
     Require all granted
    </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / <mydomain:8443.com>
  ProxyPassReverse / <mydomain:8443.com>
  <Location />
       Require all granted
   </Location>
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/leadu.co.il/combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I took the configuration from [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114967/500-internal-server-error-when-trying-to-implement-reverse-proxy-under-apache-h).

With this configuration, when I try and visit the domain I get internal error 500.

Comment: hint: `apache reverse proxy`.

Answer (score 0):

In your apache configuration file you should add the following:

If you want to serve your app from a subfolder (https://yourwebsite/express-app/):

```
    ProxyPass /express-app/ http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse /express-app/ http://localhost:3000/
```

If you want to serve your app from root (https://yourwebsite):

```
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

I assume here your app runs on port 3000. Change it if otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As you used cPanel to configure Apache, it's better to add configuration using include files, since cPanel might overwrite `/etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf`

You have to create the file `/etc/apache2/conf.d/userdata/ssl/2_4/$user/leadu.co.il/include.conf` (replace `$user` by your cPanel user) with the following content:

```
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /var/cpanel/ssl/apache_tls/leadu.co.il/combined
SSLUseStapling off
SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

For more detail, you can check https://ferpython.com/setup-fastapi-in-cpanel